# Get list of distinct file endings in a directory (UNIX shell)

Tags: linux, shell, filenames

I have a directory with many image files in different formats. I'd like to see a list of all distinct file endings in that directory, so that I can see what kind of image formats are present. So assuming there would be only `png`, `gif` and `jpg` files, my desired output would look like:

```
png
gif
jpg
```

I know how to get a list of all file endings using  `ls` and `cut`, but I don't know how to make that contain only unique entries. Is there a way to do this using only shell tools, or do I have to write a small python script or similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ ls *.* | nawk -F\. '{print $(NF);}' | sort | uniq
```

If you want to know how many of each type:

```
$ ls *.* | nawk -F\. '{print $(NF);}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Great, didn't know about the `uniq` tool - exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: +1 but this is a case where awk is overkill; you could achieve the same with `for f in ./*.*; do echo "${f##*.}"; done | sort | uniq -c` (also, one less pipe)

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way.

```
function alsoHidden {
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n';
}
$ alsoHidden | sed -E 's/.*\.(.*)/\1/' | sort -u

$ alsoHidden | tr . / | xargs -I% basename % | sort -u

$ alsoHidden | awk -F. ' !a[$NF] { print $NF; a[$NF]++ }'
```